# Report tests with excluded tags as skipped

Tags: pytest

I have several tests such as the following:

```
@pytest.mark.longrun
@pytest.mark.manual
class TestClassFake:
```

When I run eg `pytest -m "not manual"`, is there any way to have the skipped tests reported as "skipped" (as if it were `pytest.skip()`'d), rather than just not being included in the report?